# awk bash recursive brackets id sed tr

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, unique

A server provides a list of asset IDs separated by commas in square brackets after the date and colons :

```
20160420084726:-
20160420085418:[111783178, 111557953, 111646835, 111413356, 111412662, 105618372, 111413557]
20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20160420085522:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
20160420090022:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
```

The format of the input log is:

```
timestamp:ads
```

Where:
`timestamp` is in the format `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`, and `ads` is a comma separated list of ad asset IDs surrounded by square brackets, or `-` if no ads were returned.

The first part of the task is to write a script that outputs, for each ten minute slice of the day:

- Count of IDs that were returned
- Count of unique IDs that were returned
- Script should support a command line parameter to select whether unique or total IDs should be given.

Example output using the above log excerpt (in total mode):

```
20160420084:0
20160420085:26
20160420090:5
```

And in unique count mode it would give:

```
20160420084:0
20160420085:19
20160420090:5
```

I have tried this:

```
awk -F '[,:]' '
                    {
                      key = substr($1,1,11)"0"
                      count[key] += ($2 == "-" ? 0 : NF-1)
                    } 
                    END {
                    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
                    for (key in count) print key, count[key]
                  }
                    ' $LOGFILENAME | grep $DATE;
```

With the scripts given until now other scenarios fail. For example this one:

log file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sXFvLyCH8gZrXiqf095MubyP7-sLVUXt/view?usp=sharing

The first few lines of the results should be:

nonunique:

```
20160420000:1
20160420001:11
20160420002:13
20160420003:16
20160420004:3
20160420005:3
20160420010:6
```

unique:

```
20160420000:1
20160420001:5
20160420002:5
20160420003:5
20160420004:3
20160420005:3
20160420010:4
```

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: I see nothing recursive about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[]:[]+"; OFS=":" }
{
    tot = unq = 0
    time = substr($1,1,11)
    if ( /,/ ) {
        tot = split($2,tmp,/, ?/)
        for ( i in tmp ) {
            if ( !seen[time,tmp[i]]++ ) {
                unq++
            }
        }
    }
    tots[time] += tot
    unqs[time] += unq
}
END {
    for (time in tots) {
        print time, tots[time], unqs[time]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
20160420084:0:0
20160420085:26:19
20160420090:5:5
```

Massage to suit...

Comment: With other log files it does not work, it has to sum all occurrences of ten minutes interval.

Comment: All we have to work with is the example you provide in your question. If that example isn't truly representative of your real data then fix your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read; do
   dts=$( echo "$REPLY" | cut -d: -f1 )
   ids=$( echo "$REPLY" | grep -o '\[.*\]' )
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       ids=$( echo "$ids" | tr -d '[] ' | tr ',' '\n' | sort $1 )
       count=$( echo "$ids" | wc -l )
   else
       count=0
   fi
   echo $dts: $count
done
```

Run like this:

```
./script.sh [-u] <input.txt
```

Comment: With other log files it does not work, it has to sum all occurrences of ten minutes interval.

Comment: Well, you will have to modify it for whatever differences there are in the log files.